# How does a 3rd party email deliverability company such as SendGrid pulls the information from the order page to send Confirmation emails?

Tags: third-party-module, smtp

**Magento 1.9.1**

We use **Sendgrid** to send out our Emails because we had a problem with the Confirmation Emails NOT being delivered to customer's inboxes (they ended up in the SPAM folder a lot) and now it works great! (they get delivered into the customer's INBOX).

We use a very expensive solution for our mobile website - **Shopgate** and they are not able to put all the information they need into the Confirmation Email. They keep asking this:

> "....what we need to know is where we can access the information on
>   Sendgrid within Magento, and how it pulls the information from the
>   order page to send these confirmation emails. Please advise."

I don't know what to tell them anymore. I tried to tell them the Confirmation Email is being created in the standard way and then it just gets sent through SendGrid INSTEAD of smpt.myDOMAIN.com but that's not a good enough answer for them.

We have the **SMTP Pro Email Extension from ASCHRODER.com** and I think that's what handles the connection with Sendgrid.

*How would you explain this process to Shopgate?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand what sendgrid is. An smtp relay/sender.
Sendgrid do not connect, or pull any information from your magento store. It simply sends out email data given to ot via smtp.

The entire email is built in magento. Then passed to sendgrid for emailing.

There is nothing tricky or fancy going on.

I highly suggest you hire a developer/consultant to assist you with your integrations. This is a good place to get reliable devs: https://commercehero.io

In regards to your issue that your outgoing emails always end up in spam.

Without the smtp plugin, outgoing emails are sent via your server email sending capabilities. Usually sendmail or exim.

There are some possibilities:

Your server ip address was blacklisted as a know source for spam. Check via online resources if this is so. Also check your domain.

Missconfiguration of your servers smtp sending client. Ie sendmail or exim ( or whatever your linux server distro uses) possible it is not configured correctly, and its triggering spam filters. for example if incorrectly configured your server hostnane could be part of the sender envelope as xxxx@localhost. This will cause spam filtering

You need to setup spf records for your domain.

I am by no means an expert on any of the above, but those are the usual pitfalls.

Hope that helps